# issue with keychain and updates from app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, keychain

I am having a very frustrating error. I have tested for an app upgrade by first installing the previous version (1.0.1) and then running version (1.0.2). Everything worked fine. I submitted the app and then I am getting issues people are getting crashes when they upgrade. I tried doing the same thing, which is installing the 1.0.1 and then install the binary on the app store, then it crashed. I looked at the console and crash logs and I get this:

```
Jul  7 08:07:45 unknown MyApp[1429] <Warning>: KeychainUtils keychainValueForKey: - Error finding keychain value for key. Status code = -25300
Jul  7 08:07:45 unknown MyApp[1429] <Warning>: AccountSession readUserDataFromDisk - Error finding keychain value for key /var/mobile/Applications/997B32E7-6FFC-4696-9CAA-129BADE2FE64/Documents/instagram_json
Jul  7 08:07:45 unknown MyApp[1429] <Warning>: UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled is deprecated. Please use a different style.
Jul  7 08:07:45 unknown MyApp[1429] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: username)'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x33ee688f 0x367e7259 0x33ee6789 0x33ee67ab 0x33e5368b 0x14fd99 0x152319 0x1530bb 0x170299 0x3270ec59 0x32711817 0x354e7dfb 0x354e7cd0)
Jul  7 08:07:45 unknown UIKitApplication:com.firesnakelabs.pinstagram[0x14e4][1429] <Notice>: terminate called throwing an exception
>
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I know what the issue is, on upgrade the filepath it was looking for is at:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/997B32E7-6FFC-4696-9CAA-129BADE2FE64/Documents/instagram_json
```

while before the upgrade (v1.0.1) the filepath of the keychain is at:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/CEE344F7-4FE1-4455-BD6D-A4D6EAA4F5FE/Documents/instagram_json
```

and hence it can't find the key on the keychain
now here's how I determine the filePath:

```
- (NSString *)filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_json", self.identifier]];
    return filePath;
}
```

I am just taking the first path that I found. So how do I make the path consistent before and after upgrade or all the time?

I am basically using the filePath as the keychain name:

```
[attributesDictionary setObject:filePath forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]; // Use the key as the account name
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but it sounds like one of these builds is an ad hoc distributed build and the other an app store signed binary. If that's the case, the two will have different keychain values. The keychain is linked to the app's signing which differs between the two mechanisms.

Comment: ah.. I see.. so then how do I test for such cases? how do I test using the app store signed binary?

Comment: I do two things: I test the upgrades using the ad hoc versions. That's the easiest. The other thing I do is hold the approved binary for developer release and then download it with a promo code prior to releasing it. Promo codes don't obey developer holds.

Comment: So you're saying you don't release the app immediately, download it using a promo code prior to releasing it to test? But then how do I get the previous version from the app store?

Comment: Yes to the first. Until you release a new build, the old build is available on the app store. Just download it like normal.

Comment: Smart! I will start doing that from now on.

Comment: one other thing is that I just pushed an ad hoc build and it seems that the filepath is different.. why is this?

Comment: I was wondering about that. I didn't mention it because I was unsure and don't have any way to easily check at present, but I kinda thought ad hoc and app-store-signed builds installed at different paths for more or less the same reason: the install path encodes the signing principal as well.

Comment: FWIW, I think my comments on being able to use promos to test an app on developer hold are wrong. The idea works the first time you release an app with a far-future release date: you can generate a promo for the app before the release date and using the promo won't obey the release date restriction. However, you can't use that method to test releases on developer hold: until you release the hold, you can't generate promos and any promos from the previous version just download the previous version.